# How can I identify the first monday, first tuesday, ..., second monday, ..., third wednesday, ..., fourth sunday in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a column of dates backing a couple years with additional columns that split the date into year, month, day, week, and weekday (if needed).

| Date |
| --- |
| 1/1/23 |
| 1/2/23 |
| 1/3/23 |
| 1/4/23 |
| 1/5/23 |
| 1/6/23 |
| 1/7/23 |
| 1/8/23 |
| 1/9/23 |
| 1/10/23 |

I'm trying to create a new column that tells me the weekday occurrence of the month like below where once the next month comes it'll restart with the "first weekday" again.

| Date | Weekday Occurrence |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | First Sunday |
| 1/2/23 | First Monday |
| 1/3/23 | First Tuesday |
| 1/4/23 | First Wednesday |
| 1/5/23 | First Thursday |
| 1/6/23 | First Friday |
| 1/7/23 | First Saturday |
| 1/8/23 | Second Sunday |
| 1/9/23 | Second Monday |
| 1/10/23 | Second Tuesday |

I found solutions that would give me the first/last day of the month but I don't want to identify the date. I want to get the weekday occurrence based on the date.

I've thought about creating a conditional for loop but it would be huge and multiple conditions like

`if week == 1 and weekday == 0: df.occurrence = 'first monday`
etc...

Comment: suggest using [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). it's a natural language parser that produces `datetime` objects from phrases like "first week day of the month".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dateutil package and use the week name and day

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser
import calendar

data = {
    'Date': [
        '1/1/23', '1/2/23', '1/3/23', '1/4/23', '1/5/23',
        '1/6/23', '1/7/23', '1/8/23', '1/9/23', '1/10/23'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x))


def get_weekday(date):
    weekday = date.weekday()
    day = date.day
    occurrences = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth']
    weekday_name = calendar.day_name[weekday]
    
    return f"{occurrences[day // 7]} {weekday_name}"


df['Weekday Occurrence'] = df['Date'].apply(get_weekday)


print(df)
```